# has anyone had an in depth interview where all the other candidates could hear your answers

Tags: interviewing

Has anyone experienced interviewing where the candidates are interviewed around the corner of the room where all other candidates can hear your answers, some of them quite personal about your values and your experiences of a stressful situation?

When I complained about the distraction as there was also a literacy/numeracy test going on as well for each candidate, the manager made sarcastic and hostile comments about if people could not cope with such distractions maybe they should not be at the interview as that was what the job entailed.

Comment: Whether anyone has had experience with this is not relevant. Neither is the managers answer. **What is the issue you want resolved**? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Do like Cam Newton when you hear another interview and cut the interview short.

Comment: This is unprofessional behavior on their part.  Even if offered a job, I would not work there

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For your real question--an interview is a two-way street. You are there to assess the mutual fit as much as they are. While I don't personally agree with this technique, and I wouldn't do it for my industry, there may be some value in their industry. Or, they may have just found themselves in that situation with that space, and didn't consider or prioritize this concern. Either way, it seems like they failed the interview. Move along.

To answer your question in the post--no, I haven't had this situation, and I haven't interviewed people like this. But I have had an interview where the interviewer acted distracted, unconcerned, interrupted frequently and cut me off after 4-5 words of every answer. Eventually he stormed out of the room complaining. I guess I "passed" this test because he returned a few minutes later with a colleague saying this is exactly the type of discipline needed for a customer facing role. I asked some pointed questions about product quality, and now I understand why the customers get upset. So I "passed" again and moved along. There's a reason the job paid so well, and a reason people with that high salary were leaving the role. Consider yourself lucky, most bad employers don't advertise poor working conditions during an interview.

Comment: Love the last sentence!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, more than once I have been interviewed on the spot in front of others, sometimes with heavy machinery in the background.

Not in my present industry, but for low skilled forestry jobs it was fairly common to show up, talk to the foreman and boss for a few minutes then either get told you have a job or not.

But in any industry I would think that complaining at interviews is generally a bad move.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't have mentioned anything either.  Just complete the interview and walk out the door.

Comment: thank you for all of your comments/replies, much appreciated.